# Merging specific rows into columns

Tags: r, data.table, tidyr

I have longitudinal data with many columns but included here the columns of interest;

```
dfin1 <- 
 ID    ROUND   CONC    PD
  1     0      100     15
  1     2      120     10
  1     4      14      10 
  1     6      10      8
  2     0      120     15
```

and a subject level data with many columns;

```
 dfin2 <- 
  ID   HEIGHT  GENDER
   1     120     0
   2     130     1
```

for each subject, I want to add columns for the values of `CONC` and `PD` at `ROUND` 0, 2, 6 into the `df2`. Column names `CONC_ROUNDx`, `PD_ROUNDx`, where x is Round number. Output shoudl be like this:

```
 dfout <-  
  ID   HEIGHT  GENDER  CONC_ROUND0  PD_ROUND0  CONC_ROUND2  PD_ROUND2  CONC_ROUND6  PD_ROUND6   
   1     120     0      100          15          120          10          10            8      
   2     130     1      120          15           NA          NA          NA            NA
```

I am using RStudio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option with `tidyverse` where we `filter` the 'ROUND' with the values of interest, then `mutate` by adding a prefix 'ROUND' to 'ROUND' column, using `pivot_wider` (from the dev version of `tidyr`), change the data from long to wide (which can take multiple value columns) and do a join with the second dataset

```
library(dplyr) # 0.8.3
library(tidyr) # 0.8.3.9000
library(stringr)
dfin1 %>%
   filter(ROUND %in% c(0, 2, 6)) %>%
   mutate(ROUND =  str_c("ROUND", ROUND)) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = ROUND, values_from = c("CONC", "PD")) %>% 
   inner_join(dfin2, .)
#    ID HEIGHT GENDER CONC_ROUND0 CONC_ROUND2 CONC_ROUND6 PD_ROUND0 PD_ROUND2 PD_ROUND6
#1  1    120      0         100         120          10        15        10         8
#2  2    130      1         120          NA          NA        15        NA        NA
```

#### data

```
dfin1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), ROUND = c(0L, 2L, 
4L, 6L, 0L), CONC = c(100L, 120L, 14L, 10L, 120L), PD = c(15L, 
10L, 10L, 8L, 15L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

dfin2 <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, HEIGHT = c(120L, 130L), GENDER = 0:1), 
     class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: @not sure why it is giving me this error although i have dplyr and tidyr packages loaded ` Error in pivot_wider(., names_from = ROUND, values_from = c("CONC", "PD")) : 
  could not find function "pivot_wider"`

Comment: @Amer The `tidyr` package version can you check whether it is the same as I showed in the post.  It is the dev version where the `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer` is introduced

Comment: ‘tidyr’ version 0.8.3; that is the one i have

Comment: @Amer Can you try the dev version

Comment: It works but also needed to load `library(stringr)` for the str_c function! Cheers!

Comment: we i applied this to the real data frame, i ran into this error; `Error: Only bare vectors have shapes. Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace` Any idea?

Comment: calling back the trace gives this: <error>
message: Only bare vectors have shapes.
class:   `rlang_error`
backtrace:
  1. dplyr::filter(., CYCLE %in% c(0, 4, 8))
 15. dplyr::mutate(., CYCLE = str_c("CYCLE", CYCLE))
 16. tidyr::pivot_wider(...)
 17. vctrs:::shape_match(character(), x, y)
 19. vctrs:::shape_common(x, y)
  1. vctrs:::shape(x)
Call `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full backtrace.

Comment: @Amer  Can you check the `str(newdata)` with `str(exampledata)`  May be there are some attributess

Comment: column names in my df are slightly different to the example

Comment: @Amer That wouldn't be an issue if you have the same pattern as in the examplee

Comment: columns in example data are all integer but in the new data: SUBJID is a factor, CYCLE and other values are numeric. would that be an issue?

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue.  Can you convert the column 'SUBJID' to `character` class

Comment: the issue i think is in joining. how can i join by two factors `STUDYID` and `SUBJID`? when i took off `STUDYID` from the data frame, it worked but gave this error: `Joining, by = "SUBJID"
Warning message:
Column `SUBJID` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector

Comment: @Amer  Both are `factor` columns.  It is not an error but a warning suggesting that the `factor` levels are different, so converting to `character`.  If you want to remov ethat warning.  consider to change the columns to `character` class before the join i..e `as.character(SUBJID)`

Answer (score 4):

A possible approach to pivot into wide form and then join with subject level data:

```
pvt <- dcast(dfin1, ID ~ ROUND, value.var=c("CONC", "PD"))
dfin2[pvt, on=.(ID), names(pvt) := mget(paste0("i.", names(pvt)))]
```

output:

```
   ID HEIGHT GENDER CONC_0 CONC_2 CONC_4 CONC_6 PD_0 PD_2 PD_4 PD_6
1:  1    120      0    100    120     14     10   15   10   10    8
2:  2    130      1    120     NA     NA     NA   15   NA   NA   NA
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
dfin1 <- fread("ID    ROUND   CONC    PD
1     0      100     15
1     2      120     10
1     4      14      10 
1     6      10      8
2     0      120     15")
dfin2 <- fread("ID   HEIGHT  GENDER
1     120     0
2     130     1")
```